# Filling spaces on Minecraft

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

How do I fill a large space on Mine craft 1.12.2? I have tried everything! Is there some specific process to do it?

Comment: If you've tried everything, then surely you won't mind showing us a few of the things that you've done, right?

Comment: Also define "filling" a space? Is this in creative? Survival? Do you want to replace only air blocks? Do you want to replace blocks with air?

Comment: it is creative.  yes i want to replace only air blocks with white terracotta

Answer (score -1):

The syntax from the [wiki on the fill command](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Commands#fill):

```
fill <x1> <y1> <z1> <x2> <y2> <z2> <block> <dataValue|state> replace [replaceTileName] [replaceDataValue]
```

Replace x1 y1 z1 and x2 y2 z2 with any two opposing corner blocks of the region to be filled.

Replace `<block>` with the [block id](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Java_Edition_data_values#Block_IDs) you want to fill.  
Terracotta block id is `minecraft:stained_hardened_clay`.

Replace the `<dataValue|state>` with the data value of block variant you want.
White terracotta has a [dataValue](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Terracotta#Block_data) of 0.

Replace `[replaceTileName]` with the block id you want to replace.  Air block id is `minecraft:air`.

Here is the command to replace only air with white terracotta:

```
/fill <x1> <y1> <z1> <x2> <y2> <z2> minecraft:stained_hardened_clay 0 replace minecraft:air 0
```

Answer (score -1):

To start go to Options... » Chat Settings... And make sure *Reduced Debug Info* is OFF. Now look at a block and down left you'll see something like *Looking at:*
Now type in chat:   /fill (press tab and space 3 times |or| type the nulbers manually) now press enter.
look at an other block (second position) and open your chat, press arrow up so you will get your last message and now type in the 3 next coordinated from the *Looking at:* thing. If you want to fill it with redstone lamps you do this /fill    to get the blockname press F3+H so *advanced tooltips* are SHOWN. Now hover over the redstone lamp and below you will see this *minecraft:redstone_lamp* that is what should come in the  section (called *state* in minecraft). That the basics! if you do it alot you can make those regions and thing in a few seconds (i play minecraft 5years and im still learning advanced command block features) so take you time!!! how it works for you
A fast example /fill 5 60 5 -5 60 -5 minecraft:quartz_block
will fill 100 blocks with quartz_block. if you want like stained_glass but *red* then the  will ben *minecraft:stained_glass 14* why 14??? if you hover over the block right of the name you'll see (#0095/*14*) ;) if you undrstand you can now 80% use the /fill command. there is only 1 feature more and thats putting *replace*   *hollow*   or   *mask* after the 
but don't focus on that. Hope this was clear enough